# Can we figure an EAP controller using Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, tp-link

I'd just like to know if we can access the EAP Controller for Tp-Link Ac1900 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Access Point in Ubuntu 16.04.  Most of the guides are showing the EAP Controller for windows only.  I am very very new to networking.  Any answer or suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to install and run the Windows software through Wine? Presumably the management application uses some IP-based network protocol which should work through Wine.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but i started checking this yesterday and according to the q13 on their faq (http://www.tp-link.fr/faq-865.html) at the moment its only available on windows.